# A phrase which contains "until immediately after" confuses me

Tags: sentence-structure

Could you, please, rephrase the following sentence?

> "please wait to submit your project A, until immediately after you
>   submit the project B"

"until immediately after" confuses me and I don't understand in which order should I submit the projects.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Submit B, and then immediately submit A.

Answer (score 3):

Break it down this way:

> Please wait to submit your project A.

Okay, so then when should I actually submit it?

> immediately after you submit the project B.

So you wait on *A* until after *B*.  How long after *B*?  Immediately after.